# No route found for "GET /test/" 404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException 1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException »

Tags: symfony

Hi I am new to symforny2 I have this Exception **No route found for "GET /test/"** when i use the URL:

```
http://local.symfony2.com/app_dev.php/test/
```

i have this in Controller:

```
namespace My\testBundle\Controller;

namespace  My\testBundle\Entity;
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
   /**
   * @Route("/test/", name="test")
   */
   public function testAction()
   {
      $id = 1; // ID du bureau de test que l'on a enregistré précédemment

      $desk = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MytestBundle:Desk')->find($id);

      return array('desk' => $desk);
   }
}
```

src/MytestBundle/ressources/views/default/test.html.twig

```
<h1>{{ desk.title }}</h1>
<p>
    {{ desk.description }}
</p>
<h3>Commentaires</h3>
<ul>
{% for com in desk.comments %}
    <li>
        <h4>Commentaire du {{ com.createdAt|date('d/m/Y') }}</h4>
        <p>
            {{ com.description }}
        </p>
    </li>
{% else %}
    <li>Aucun commentaire</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I have two entities Desk and DeskComment.
any help!!

Comment: Seems like you haven't imported the correct routes. Please see http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#activation

Comment: Did you import routes from a controller class in routing.yml? Furthermore, to render your twig file you need to use `@Template` in your routing

Comment: I modified the src/MytestBundle/ressources/config/rooting.yml:

Comment: test:
    pattern:  /test/
    defaults: {_controller: MytestBundle:Default:index}

Comment: i removed in controller /**
  * @Route("/test/", name="test")
  */                                                                     noxw i have another problem:                                                 FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class My\testBundle\Entity\DefaultController in /var/www/html/Symfony/src/My/testBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 15

Comment: @user3816170 What are you using as routing? yaml, annotation?

Comment: now i use yml annotation !!

Comment: But you can use just one of them; take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html and also http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#basic-route-configuration

Comment: yess i said that i removed  /** * @Route("/test/", name="test") */ now i use just the annotation yml!!

Comment: now i have another Exception:                                               FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class My\testBundle\Entity\DefaultController in /var/www/html/Symfony/src/My/testBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 15

Comment: You have the namespace set twice.

Comment: but i have to add the namespace of the entities !!!

Comment: when i removed the namespace i have this Exception:                           Controller "My\testBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction" for URI "/test/" is not callable.

Comment: After changing from annotation to yaml did you remove `type: annotation` from `config.yml` in config; and make sure you defined the proper routing resource as `resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"` or any other path you have for it

Answer (score 0):

can you copypaste

```
<yourbundle> / config / routing.yml
```

and

```
<root> / app / config / routing.yml

<root> / app / config / routing_dev.yml
```

probably a routing failure